# Writing a list of objects to realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I just start thinking about implementing Realm and have some newbie doubts.

For example I receive a list of objects which I transform into realm objects. How can I write the whole list directly to Realm, without writing each object separately?

A typical workaround comes into my mind, which would be defining a bigger object which contains this list as a property and writing that bigger object to the DB. But is it possible to write directly the obtained list of objects to DB without something that encapsulates them?

And also when preparing this list of Realm objects, I basically have a list of dictionaries. What's the best approach into transforming all of them directly into a list of Realm objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to confirm. When you mention your list of objects at the top and then mention that you have a list of dictionaries, are they the same thing?

If they are, and your data is coming down as a set of dictionaries, as long as the key names match the properties in your Realm Object models, then you can simply loop through each dictionary and pass each one to Realm to create it as a new entry in the database:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    for dictionary in dictionaries {
        realm.create(MyObject.self, value: dictionary, update: false)
    }
}
```

More information on that API can be found on [Realm Swift's documentation page](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-objects).

If your objects don't map directly to the properties in your Realm file, then you're going to need to manually reformat the structure of your list of objects until either could be inserted as a dictionary, or you can manually create your own Realm Object instances off them.

Comment: Yep, this is how I made it in the end. I had to make a local "reformat" of the JSON dictionaries I receive and then pass that dictionary directly to the Realm Objects constructor. And basically I create this objects outside real.write and then in realm.write I directly use the realm.add for a collection of objects.